# Ran into a Python Syntax Error for the below code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to the world of programming and ran into this syntax error when i ran the code it gives me a syntax error and highlights the word element in red.Please help

```
given_list = [5,4,4,3,1,-2,-2,-5]
total = 0
for given element in given_list:
    if element <= 0:
        break
    total += element
print total
```

I have no previous work experience so please help me.I think the error is because of some extra space or so but i have no idea.

Answer (score 3):

Python identifiers can't use space symbols (well, it is logical). So you can't use `given element` variable, you should replace it with `element`. Here is the correct code:

```
given_list = [5,4,4,3,1,-2,-2,-5]
total = 0
for element in given_list:
    if element <= 0:
        break
    total += element
print(total)  # Works both in Python2 and Python3
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does not allow you to use spaces in identifiers. Because of this, you cannot use `given element` as an identifier name. Instead, you should try using `given_element`. Another problem here is that you are using `print total`. This will not work in python 3.x, instead use `print(total)`, as it will work in python 2.x and 3.x. Here is the code with these corrections:

```
given_list = [5,4,4,3,1,-2,-2,-5]
total = 0
for given_element in given_list:
    if given_element <= 0:
        break
    total += given_element
print(total)
```